# Single Application Mode OSX

Tags: macos, mac, macos-highsierra

I'm trying to activate Single Application Mode on Mac OS 10.13.4 and it doesn't seem to be working–– has anyone tried this recently?
I'm using the command:
    defaults write com.apple.dock single-app -bool true; killall Dock

It does indeed write that change-- if I type:
    defaults read com.apple.dock single-app
it registers as "1", but the feature doesn't work.

Any advice?
Thanks!
-Gabe

Comment: You can turn this on using TinkerTool.

Answer (score 1):

Single application mode was never officially a feature of macOS -- it was only ever available using an undocumented preference -- and it is no longer available in current releases.

You can get similar results by running applications in full-screen mode, or by using the "Hide Others" command (under the application menu).

Comment: Ah, thank you for that! It's a shame that they took that out!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you still need this. But, here's what I did to accomplish Single-Application on my late 2012 Mac Mini using macOS Mojave (10.14.6). But, was based upon instructions I read for an earlier O/S version.

- Open Terminal
- enter: defaults write com.apple.dock single-app -bool
  TRUE
- When prompt returns enter: killall Dock

On my system, after a couple of seconds, my background turned black for a moment before returning to the normal state. Then a couple of minutes later it did the same thing again.

Now, I click on a program in the dock and the others minimize.

FWIW, to reverse the change you're supposed to issue the same commands, only replacing TRUE with FALSE in the first line.

Hope that helps anybody that stumbles upon this post.